# Implement in Haskell the Church encoding of the pair for polymorphic λ-calculus/System F

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, polymorphism, lambda-calculus, church-encoding

I want to implement the [Church encoding of the pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_pairs) in polymorphic lambda calculus in Haskell.

On page 77, section 8.3.3 of [Peter Selinger's notes on lambda calculus](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/papers/lambdanotes.pdf), he gives a construction of the cartesian product of two types as

A×B = ∀α.(A→B→α)→α
⟨M,N⟩ = Λα.λf<sup>A→B→α</sup>.fMN

For another source, on page 54, section 4.2.3 of [Dider Rémy's notes on lambda calculus](http://gallium.inria.fr/~remy/mpri/cours2.pdf), he defines the Church encoding of the pair in polymorphic λ-calculus/System F as

Λα₁.Λα₂.λx₁∶α₁.λx₂∶α₂.Λβ.λy∶α₁→α₂→β. y x₁ x₂

I think Rémy is saying the same thing, just more verbosely, as Selinger.

Anyway, according to Wikipedia, the type system for Haskell is based on [System F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F), so I am hoping it is possible to implement this Church encoding directly in Haskell. I've got:

```
pair :: a->b->(a->b->c)->c
pair x y f = f x y
```

but I wasn't sure how to do the projections.

Λα.Λβ.λp<sup>α×β</sup>.pα(λx<sup>α</sup>.λy<sup>β</sup>.x)

Do I use the Haskell `forall` for the capital lambda type quantifier?

This is basically the same as [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33597144/swift-higher-order-function-church-pair-aka-cons-with-generic-parameter-types), but in Haskell instead of Swift. I thought the additional context and the change of venue might make it more sensible.

Comment: Do the $$ dollar sign delimited sentences not invoke the latex renderer on Stackoverflow?

Comment: Unfortunately, they don't :-( I guess there's not enough math around SO (except on the Haskell tag ;-))

Comment: The type of a pair of `a` and `b` in Haskell syntax is `forall c . (a->b->c) -> c`. So the types of fst and snd are `(forall c . (a->b->c) -> c) -> a` and `(forall c . (a->b->c) -> c) -> b`. From their type signatures, their definitions are quite trivial.

Comment: [This blog post](http://www.jonmsterling.com/posts/2011-12-28-expressing-church-pairs-with-types.html) by Jonathon Sterling seems to be doing something like a church encoding in Haskell, and notice that he does use `Rank2Types`. But I couldn't follow all the Haskell bits. Antal's answer below keeps it to the bare minimum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you're indeed correct that Selinger and Rémy are saying the same thing; the difference is that Rémy is defining the *pair constructor function* ⟨–,–⟩, which takes as arguments M and N (his x₁ and x₂) along with their types (α₁ and α₂); the remainder of his definition is just the definition of ⟨M,N⟩ with β and y where Selinger has α and f.

Alright, with that taken care of, let's start moving towrads projections.  The first thing to note is the relation between ∀, Λ, →, and λ, and their equivalents in Haskell.  Recall that ∀ and its inhabitants Λ operate on *types*, where → and its inhabitants λ operate on *values*.  Over in Haskell-land, most of these correspondences are easy, and we get the following table

```
          System F                             Haskell
Terms (e)     :  Types (t)        Terms (e)       ::  Types (t)
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
λx:t₁.(e:t₂)  :  t₁ → t₂          \x::t₁.(e::t₂)  :: t₁ -> t₂
Λα.(e:t)      :  ∀α.t             (e::t)          :: forall α. t
```

The term-level entries are easy: → becomes `->` and λ becomes `\`.  But what about ∀ and Λ?

By default, in Haskell, all the ∀s are implicit.  Every time we refer to a type variable (a lower-case identifier in a type), it's implicitly universally quantified.  So a type signature like

```
id :: a -> a
```

corresponds to

id : ∀α.α→α

in System F.  We can turn on the language extension `ExplicitForAll` and gain the ability to write those explicitly:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}
id :: forall a. a -> a
```

By default, however, Haskell only lets us put those quantifiers at the start of our definitions; we want the System F-style ability to put `forall`s anywhere in our types.  For this, we turn on `RankNTypes`.  In fact, all Haskell code from now on will use

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, TypeOperators #-}
```

(The other extension allows type names to be operators.)

Now that we know all that, we can try to write down the definition of ×.  I'll call its Haskell version `**` to keep things distinct (although we could use `×` if we wanted).  Selinger's definition is

A×B = ∀α.(A→B→α)→α

so the Haskell is

```
type a ** b = forall α. (a -> b -> α) -> α
```

And as you said, the creation function is

```
pair :: a -> b -> a ** b
pair x y f = f x y
```

But what happened to our Λs?  They're there in the System F definition of ⟨M,N⟩, but `pair` doesn't have any!

So this is the last cell in our table: in Haskell, *all Λs are implicit*, and there's not even an extension to make them explicit.¹  Anywhere they would show up, we just ignore them, and *type inference* fills them in automatically.  So, to answer one of your explicit questions directly, you use the Haskell `forall` to represent the System F ∀, and *nothing* to represent the System F type lambda Λ.

So you give the definition of the first projection as (reformatted)

proj₁ = Λα.Λβ.λp:α×β.p α (λx:α.λy:β.x)

We translate this to Haskell by ignoring all Λs *and their applications* (and eliding type annotations²), and we get

```
proj₁ = \p. p (\x y -> x)
```

or

```
proj₁ p = p (\x _ -> x)
```

Our System F version has the type

proj₁ : ∀α.∀β. α×β → α

or, expanded

proj₁ : ∀α.∀β. (∀γ. α → β → γ) → α

and indeed, our Haskell version has the type

```
proj₁ :: α ** β -> α
```

which again expands to

```
proj₁ :: (forall γ. α -> β -> γ) -> α
```

or, to make the binding of `α` and `β` explicit,

```
proj₁ :: forall α β. (forall γ. α -> β -> γ) -> α
```

And for completeness, we also have

proj₂ : ∀α.∀β. α×β → β
proj₂ = Λα.Λβ.λp:α×β.p β (λx:α.λy:β.y)

which becomes

```
proj₂ :: α ** β -> β
proj₂ p = p (\_ y -> y)
```

which is probably unsurprising at this point :-)

---

¹ Relatedly, all Λs can be *erased* at compile time – type information is not present in compiled Haskell code!

² The fact that we elide Λs means that type variables *aren't bound* in the terms.  The following is an error:

```
id :: a -> a
id x = x :: a
```

because it's treated as though we'd written

```
id :: forall a. a -> a
id x = x :: forall b. b
```

which of course doesn't work.  To get around this, we can turn on the language extension `ScopedTypeVariables`; then, any type variables bound in an explicit `forall` are in scope in the term.  So the first example still breaks, but

```
id :: forall a. a -> a
id x = x :: a
```

works fine.

Comment: Thank you, this answer is fantastic.

Comment: I will note for the record that I also found https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/guest-posts/2014-12-18-rank-n-types.html and http://sleepomeno.github.io/blog/2014/02/12/Explaining-Haskell-RankNTypes-for-all/ useful for understanding RankNType polymorphism

Comment: I also found https://wiki.haskell.org/Rank-N_types and the linked stackoverflow answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589556/why-are-difference-lists-not-an-instance-of-foldable/15593349#15593349. They  have useful reference code, but were not very useful for learning the topic.

Comment: One question, what did you need the `TypeOperators` directive for? Does it allow `**` to be a type constructor?

Comment: @ziggurism: I'm glad you found this helpful!  Yes, `TypeOperators` is just to allow the use of `**` as a type – I could have called it `Pair` instead and skipped that.  (The [GHC manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#type-operators) has more details.)

Comment: Nicely done. About "there's not even an extension to make [type arguments] explicit": we might get it in the future :-) https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TypeApplication

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
Λα.Λβ.λp:α×β.p α (λx:α.λy:β.x)
```

Just remove all the type arguments, both in application and abstraction:

```
λp:α×β.p (λx:α.λy:β.x)
```

In Haskell, without type annotations:

```
\p -> p (\x y -> x)
```